# Tracking self measurements

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, experiment-design, measurement

Pretty new to stats (and health related experiments).

I bought a blood pressure monitor and want to measure my blood pressure daily ( few times at different times of day).

Also, every month, I want to do a experiment.

**Example**:

First month, I want to workout daily.

Second month, I won't work out.

And I want to compare how blood pressure readings compare with readings in second month.

What is the statistical way to do this, i.e. how do i make sure readings in one month are more statistically significant.

Workout is just an example. I am planning run to multiple experiments on myself (eating spicy foods, not eating spicy foods, taking shower with cold water...)

Any help on how to start would be highly appreciated.

Comment: collect your data, state the null and alternative hypotheses and assumptions,  analyze sample data, see example here http://stattrek.com/hypothesis-test/mean.aspx?Tutorial=AP

Answer (score 0):

The main consideration is to try and keep comparisons as uniform as possible, i.e. the only thing that should differ is the change in behaviour. That would mean the following:

1. Decide beforehand when measurements will be taken and stick to the schedule rigorously. For example, don’t take some morning measurements before breakfast and some after. Try and stick to exact times – and circumstances – as far as possible.
2. Your 1st month should be the control. This is the baseline to which you would compare data from the other months. If you exercise in the first month but not the second, your measurements in the second month would still be a reflection of the fitness gains from the first month. Instead, the first month should be the “do nothing” month.
3. Take a representative number of measurements of each time of day for each “experiment”. I would suggest taking at least 20 for each month/experiment. So that would be 20 morning measurements, 20 at noon and 20 in the evening (or whenever you decide to take the measurements). This is linked to the following point, namely…
4. Only compare “like with like” measurements to determine the experimental effects (e.g. exercise, spicy food, etc.). So morning measurements in month 1 should be compared with morning measurements from month 2, noon measurements from month 1 with noon measurements from month 2, etc. Otherwise you have confounding variables such as time of day. For example, morning measurements from month 1 to noon measurements from month 2 are not comparable if the noon measurements are taken after a stressful 1.5 hour commute and 3 hours of fighting with co-workers.
5. If you want to compare the effect of the time of day (e.g. the effect of the commute and co-workers), then this should be done within months. So compare morning and noon for month 1, morning and noon for month 2, etc. Alternatively, you could group ALL morning measurements from all months and compare them to ALL noon measurements from all months.